# Can C++ class templates take method names as template parameters?

Tags: c++, templates, class-template

Just like the title asks, can C++ class templates take method names as template parameters?

For instance,

```
template <T>
class Foo
{
public:
    void T(int bar);
};
```

Comment: I really can't think of where this would ever be useful. Do you have a specific problem, or is this just hypothetical?

Comment: @chris - Not saying it ever would be. It was just a question that came across my mind.

Comment: If you're doing what I think you're doing, you may find info on functors useful. (and no, you can't do this, but a text file + c++ compiler could have told you that).

Comment: @WhozCraig - Yes it could, but I don't have tons of compilers at my disposal to try on all of the various platforms, nor would I have any more of an explanation as to why it wasn't included or why it would be theoretically unstable ;)

Comment: @Di-0xide It wouldn't take tons of of compilers; only one that follows that standard. And the functionality was included in several ways, just not *this* way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, the C++ core language does not have any means of handling *names*.

Some possibilities:

- Handle names via the preprocessor, ie., ugly macros.
  Note: the Boost parameters library uses some *undocumented* Boost macro trickery that is very relevant here. I used that for a [general options class](http://alfps.wordpress.com/2010/05/19/cppx-how-to-do-typed-optional-arguments-in-c98/) thing once. Sorry I can't remember much about it, but essentially it supports a kind of variadic macros for C++03.
- Do your own custom preprocessing, i.e. script based.
- Put the burden on the client code programmer, somehow.

For those who wonder, what does one need this for?, a case in point is how to something like Python's library "named tuple" class, in C++, where the programmer provides the names of the tuple members.